# How to seperate the CA server from Master (basic setup)?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I followed [Centralize the Certificate Authority](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scaling_multiple_masters.html#centralize-the-certificate-authority) guide to seperate my `ca` from the `master` however I'm running into trouble.

### My Setup

#### Hosts file

I have the following in the `/etc/hosts` file on all hosts:

```
192.168.33.11 puppetcaserver
192.168.33.10 puppet
```

#### Puppet Master config

```
[main]

    ca_server = puppetcaserver

[master]
    ca = false
```

#### Puppet CA config

```
[master]
    ca         = true
```

#### Agent

```
 [master]
    ca_server = puppetcaserver
    server    = puppet
```

I can successfully start the CA. The puppet master fails with:

```
Error: Could not run: Could not retrieve certificate for centos65-box-1 and not running on a valid certificate authority
```

[Full debug logs here](http://pastebin.com/E9710Zi5)

*Puppet version used: 3.7.3*

Can someone please highlight what the issue is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the agent machine, it does not make sense to specify options in the `[master]` section of `puppet.conf`. The `[agent]` section is eligible, but to keep it simple, just stick to the `[main]` section.

```
[main]
ca_server = puppetcaserver
server    = puppet
```